# Search Console shows no valid pages for JobPosting

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, google-search-console

I have created structured data in my page for [`JobPosting`](http://schema.org/JobPosting) markup and I want to see the results in Google Search Console.

When I go to https://search.google.com/search-console/jobs, I see many warnings and no valid page.

When I test it in https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool, it returns valid markups with warnings.

I want to know how this console works and why no valid pages shows to me?

This is how I saw the status:

[image: Search console markup status]

Comment: I can’t access this search console tool (seems to require an account), but wouldn’t it only show pages as "Valid" if these pages have no warnings? There are three categories, and a page can only be in one of them.

Comment: I have pages that have no warning, but it is not in the valids.